# how to delete all Facebook events in Facebook analytics?

Tags: facebook-analytics

Is there a quick way to delete all our Facebook events in Facebook Analytics?

We have 1000 events and to do it manually will take days.

Answer (score 5):

Bulk deactivate was recently introduced in the product. Go to the Events screen and click the 'Deactivate' button at the top right.

[image: Bulk deactivation]

Comment: Is there any Delete option ?